# Why does my HTTP request work in a form but not AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, forms, postman

I'm using "Woofoo" forms as a service, they give me this code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" no validate action="https://kingofthestack.wufoo.com/forms/z116los31o2hqhx/#public">
  <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="email"/>
  <textarea id="Field4" name="Field4"></textarea>
  <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" id="idstamp" name="idstamp" value="my-secret-key" />
</form>
```

It works in postman, but when I use postman's generated code in jQuery I get `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: It's a cross domain restriction. You can't just post data onto any server.

Comment: @DinoMyte I'm confused how a POST made with a form can be treated differently from one made with Javascript. Shouldn't I be able to make them function the same?

Comment: check the action property in the form tag and make sure it points to the same domain making the request.

Comment: multipart/formdata is not the usual type for form data unless you're uploading files.  It's usually application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so your jscript maybe setting a type that the server doesn't want.